# page redirection c#-address bar url

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

i have a scenario in which i want to set a page redirection from a custom url to my web site.For instance i might want http://support.mydomain.com to open page http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/support/index.aspx but the trick is that i want the address bar to show http://support.mydomain.com and not http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com/support/index.aspx. I m using aspnet c# web forms.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't sound good especially if its on your subdomain. However the answer would be to use an Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). Even though, strictly speaking, it is a workaround.

Comment: url rewrite is an option although i don't think is going to work.I m thinking that what i m asking is a little bit weird.I mean is it possible to just change the url to what ever you want?No.So i believe i haven't gotten clear in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Server.Transfer()
```

Because it doesn't change the url bar. Also
The best  thing is using

```
 Configure Url Rewrite in IIS
```